# Size of array generated by <>?

Tags: arrays, perl, size, glob

If I want to find the size of an array generated by `<>`, why doesn't the following work?

```
print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: " scalar(<*.PDF *.DOC>);
```

It gives the name of the first matching file instead.

Comment: @user2864740 How do I turn the list into an array in the same statement?

Comment: Oh, I was so wrong: see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#glob-EXPR "In *scalar context*, glob iterates through such filename expansion.."

Answer (score 10):

Let's start by clearing up some of your misconceptions.

- [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)<sup>[1]</sup> never returns an array. Operators don't return arrays<sup>[2]</sup>; they return scalars. Sometimes none, sometimes one, sometimes many.
- `scalar` affects operators, not the values they return. Specifically, `scalar` causes the operator within to be evaluated in scalar context.
- How an operator is affected by context is up to each individual operator. The only constant is that they must return exactly one scalar in scalar context. There is a lot of [variety](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347416) in what they choose to return in scalar context.

In scalar context, `glob` acts an iterator, returning the next item it would have returned in list context, or `undef` to signal there are no further values to return.

---

Solutions:

- A memory-efficient solution:

  ```
  my $num_files = 0;
  ++$num_files while <*.PDF *.DOC>; 
  print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: $num_files\n";
  ```
- A faster solution:

  ```
  my @qfns = <*.PDF *.DOC>; 
  print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: " . @qfns . "\n";
  ```
- An inlined version of the above:

  ```
  print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: " . @{[ <*.PDF *.DOC> ]} . "\n";
  ```
- An even faster, less wasteful, but more advanced solution:

  ```
  print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: " . ( () = <*.PDF *.DOC> ) . "\n";
  ```

  The [list assignment operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) in scalar context returns the number of scalars returned by its RHS.
- Cleaner/clearer?

  ```
  my $num_files = () = <*.PDF *.DOC>;
  print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: $num_files\n";
  ```

---

1. `<*.PDF *.DOC>` is a shortcut for `glob(qq<*.PDF *.DOC>)`
2. Except for `@a` in certain situations (including `\@a`, `@a = LIST`, and array manipulators like `push @a, LIST`).

Comment: I'd use concatenation instead of `0+` to enforce the scalar context - e.g. `print "Number of .DOC and .PDF files is: " . ( () = <*.PDF *.DOC> );`

Comment: @Dave Cross, That's what I would use too, and since I'm not sticking to what the OP used anyway, I've updated my answer